How do i decode a raw h264 data with ffmpeg cpp
I'm trying to decode raw h264 data recived from tcp client and display it in opencv with ffmpeg cpp. Please help I haven't found any youtube video on how to do this.

Welcome to Super User! Issues specific to programming and software development are off topic, see on-topic . Try [SO] but please first read how to ask.

Welcome to Super User! Please read the tags before posting your question. You are asking an off-topic question. See [help/on-topic].
